# Containing div smaller than children

Tags: css

Given the following

```css
#container {
    border:solid 3px red;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    background-color: coral;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left'>Left content</div>
    <div id='right'>Right content</div>
</div>
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/JCPEH/1/)

Why does `container` apparently not have any area (that is, it has a zero height, plus the border)?  I naively expected it to be as tall as the child `div`s that it contains.

What is the proper way to set this up so that the `div` containing the two children is as tall as the children?

Comment: everyone posting the same answer, go point-hunters go, its funny how ppl spam the same answer instead of upvoting the right one.

Comment: @Toping They published it in the same minute, most probably they didn't know there were other answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to clear your floats.  You can do this via a clearfix class:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

#container {
    border:solid 3px red;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    background-color: coral;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' class="clearfix">
    <div id='left'>Left content</div>
    <div id='right'>Right content</div>
</div>
```

or a clearing element:

```css
.clear {
  clear:both;
}

#container {
    border:solid 3px red;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    background-color: coral;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left'>Left content</div>
    <div id='right'>Right content</div>
    <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JCPEH/5/

Answer (score 4):

This is because `floats` are not part of the layout until they are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

A `float` like some other "commands" (like position relative/absolute/fix) removes the element from the normal rendering flow.
One result, it is no longer affecting it's parent element way of rendering.

[You can enlighten yourself here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 1):

before closing the big div add a `<div id="clear"></div>` and in css add #clear{clear:both;}

Answer (score 0):

Set the position to absolute for the container, that fixes the problem. http://jsbin.com/ifojug/1/ jsfiddle doesnt work on my browser for some reason

Comment: This may be a non-canonical answer, and not particularly maintainable or intuitive. But it *does* address the OP's problem, and others like it.